# Return false is not working AJAX

Tags: javascript, ajax

I have got this in my index.htm

```
<form>
<input onkeyup="firstnamecheck(this.value)" type="text" name="firstname" id="Start" class="Inputs" />
<button type="submit" name="Murad"  id="tester"title="Register" >Register</button>
</form>
```

And this in reg.js

```
function firstnamecheck(str) {
    if (str.length == 0) { 
        document.getElementById("firster").innerHTML = "";
        return false;
    }else if(3>str.length>0){
        document.getElementById("firster").innerHTML = "Firstname should be more than 3 charachters";
        return false; 
    }else if(str.length>30){
        document.getElementById("firster").innerHTML = "Firstname should be less than 30 charachters";

       return false; 
    } else {
        var xmlhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
        xmlhttp.onreadystatechange = function() {
            if (xmlhttp.readyState == 4 && xmlhttp.status == 200) {
                document.getElementById("firster").innerHTML = xmlhttp.responseText;
            }
        };
        xmlhttp.open("POST", "era.php?f=" + str, true);
        xmlhttp.send();
    }
}
```

But even when it gives error i can still submit form even though there is return false.

Comment: @PatrickEvans: The `return false` aspect is a red herring. The real problem is that the wrong block is getting run (the `else` block at the end, instead of one of the conditional blocks).

Comment: No.I want to show if user have errors while he or she types

Comment: Oh yea forgot they were trying to do an ajax request, nevermind

Comment: Also, you need to return from the handler.

Answer (score 0):

Compound range comparisons like

```
if(3>str.length>0)
```

don't work in JavaScript, or most (but not all!) other languages whose syntax derives from B (C, C++, C#, D, Java, JavaScript, etc.).

Instead, you have to list the two comparisons separately:

```
if (3 > str.length && str.length > 0)
```

Answer (score 0):

In addition to @TJCrowder's answer, there's something possibly even more important:

Your `return false;` is going to the `onkeyup` event of the `input` element, not the `submit` event of the `form`!

In fact, there is nothing that attempts to stop the form submitting.

Comment: But how can i put this functions in form

Comment: Well honestly just doing `<input type="text" minlength="3" maxlength="30" />` would be better than all that JavaScript.

Comment: User can easily change that from dev tools.

Comment: So? Use can easily submit whatever the hell they want to your server anyway. It's the server's job to validate.

Comment: So i don't want users to submit whatever they want

Comment: Tough. They're gonna do it anyway ;) You control your server. That is your realm. The user's browser, however... you can send stuff to it, but you can never control what it sends to you.